# Is there a way to show a message from a Composer repository?

Tags: php, composer-php

If I had a Composer [repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#composer) (not a Composer package or a Git repository) that lists packages and that people could include in their `composer.json` under the `repositories` section, would it be possible to display a message from the owners of the repository?

So, for example, if I have a repository at `example.com/packages.json` and a user adds the following to their project's `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://example.com"
        }
```

how would I add something to my `packages.json` that says "Hello, this is the example.com repository"?

Comment: Someone tried with that in the JS world. It caused quite a bit of outcry. https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/cvo87k/popular_javascript_library_starts_showing_ads_in/

Comment: No, you can't. This was possible on npm, but removed due to lot's of misusage.

Comment: The NPM functionality was for packages, not repositories.

Comment: Which kind of `packages.json` are you talking about? My PHP project don't have such a file

Comment: @NicoHaase it's a file that you need to create when you want to host your own [repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#composer), instead of or in addition to https://packagist.org/. It's not a file you would have in your PHP project.

Comment: Thanks @DelenaMalan for the editing - makes it much more clear what I was attempting to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a way.

You can decide whether you want to display an "info" or a "warning" message and then set either "info" or "warning" in `packages.json` to the message that you want to be displayed.

Then you also need to set either "info-versions" or "warning-versions" to the versions of Composer for which you want to display the message. If you want to display it for all versions of Composer, you could use `>=0.0.0`.

If you're interested, the source code where Composer calls a function called [outputWarnings](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Util/HttpDownloader.php#L322) to display the messages is [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php#L1031).

The message(s) will be displayed every time you run a Composer command that needs to fetch packages from the repository, including `composer install`, `composer update` and `composer require`.

Here is an example `packages.json` file that will display both a warning and an info message:

```
{
    "packages": {},
    "warning": "Warning message",
    "warning-versions": ">=0.0.0",
    "info": "Info message",
    "info-versions": ">=0.0.0"
}
```

I've added this file to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/delenamalan/3c0d998a316031af8f0f9c0165eacc28). You can try it out by adding it as a repository to your `composer.json` file and then running `composer install`:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/delenamalan/3c0d998a316031af8f0f9c0165eacc28/raw/491d2716bb8d36fea562633f2384340f560aceb6"
        }
    ],
```

Here is an example output:

```
$ composer install                                                        
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/delenamalan/3c0d998a316031af8f0f9c0165eacc28/raw/491d2716bb8d36fea562633f2384340f560aceb6: 
Warning message
Info from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/delenamalan/3c0d998a316031af8f0f9c0165eacc28/raw/491d2716bb8d36fea562633f2384340f560aceb6: 
Info message
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```